# Dynamically changing TextView color for Three different group in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, getview

[image: this is current output]

I am trying to develop a `ListView` like a Index. In my case their are three level of list, chapter, subchapter and child.. successfully i implement three level.

I want to change three different color for all three list.

**Tried:**

1. I tried to 3 level expentable listview but i cant able to achieve.
2. so i tried Listview more dynamically with single array..

**Now i want to change list color in listview by getview method**

this is my getview() for adding subchapter to list:

```
            for (int i = listsubchapt.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

                Mainarray.add(pos + 1, listsubchapt.get(i));
                Mainarrayid.add(pos + 1, listsubchaptid.get(i));

                //System.out.println("mainarraywithsub==++ " + Mainarray);
                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = (new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                        IndexChapter.this, R.layout.singlerow,
                        R.id.textView1, Mainarray){@Override
                        public View getView(int position,
                                View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                            LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
                                    Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                         convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.singlerow, null);

                         for(int i=0;i<Mainarray.size();i++){

                            String sample=Mainarray.get(i);
                            String[] items = sample.split(":"); 
                            if (items.length == 1) {
                                TextView txt = ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1));
                                txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);

                            }else if(items.length == 2){
                                TextView txt = ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1));
                                txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                            }else if(items.length == 3){
                                TextView txt = ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1));
                                txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                            }else{
                                TextView txt = ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1));
                                txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.CYAN);
                            }
                         }
                            return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                        }});


                clientdetailslist.setAdapter(adapter);
                clientdetailslist.setSelection(pos-1);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
```

**Edit :**

its moving to length=1 block and changing all the values to cyan color.

Comment: what is your problem?

Comment: @SweetWisherシ i want to give three difference color for chapter,subchapter and child

Comment: then what this do `txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);`?

Comment: `return convertView` instead of `return super.getView(position, convertView, parent);`

Comment: @SweetWisherシ all values in the list are changing to blue color.. but i want to change subchapter alone change to blue color

Comment: what is `items.length` ? debug and see in which if block it goes

Comment: nope.. return convertview does not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66993/discussion-between-sweetwisher--and-prabhakaran).

Comment: **its moving to length=1 block and changing all the values to cyan color.** means your Mainarray.get(i) is returning the first main chapter's text. Debug and check.

Comment: @MagicalPhoenixϡ ya i debugged its moving to correct blocks of statement but its return all the values in cyan color.. i think want to define the position.. but dnt know where nu can u help me???

Comment: Do you mean it changed to proper color previously and then overwritten with CYAN?

Comment: i am not sure.. while debugging its moving to correct blocks but while running on mobile its just changing all cyan color

Comment: Log a line in all if block and check whether its overwriting or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instance of `Expentable listview` you can use `listview`.

```
   @Override
   public View getView(int position,
     View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater mInflater = (LayoutInflater)getSystemService(
                        Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.singlerow, parent, false);
        TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        RelativeLayout txt = ((RelativeLayout) rowView.findViewById(R.id.clicked));
        
        textView.setText(Mainarray.get(position));
        
        String s = Mainarray.get(position);
        String s2 = s.substring (1,7);
        String[] items = s2.split(":");
        if (items.length == 1) {
      //chapter color
      txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
      
     }else if(items.length == 2){
      //subchapter color
      txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#E6F5FF"));
     }else if(items.length == 3){
      //child color
      txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#CCEBFF"));
     }else{
      // else block if u need
      txt.setBackgroundColor(Color.MAGENTA);
     }


        return rowView;

   }}
```

**Now my Screen is:**

[image: after changed color my screen]

Answer (score 0):

Return convertView instead of super.getView(...). Here are some examples: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

Comment: see my output image.. i want to show the difference by colors.. like chapter,subchapter,child